# Get year from array of dates

Tags: javascript

i have array of dates `["2003-05-13T19:00:00.000Z", "1998-02-03T20:00:00.000Z"]` from which I want to get year from I am using getFullYear() but I get error that it is not a function, what am I doing wrong?

```
this.childEndYear = this.data.underageChildInfo?.map(i => (i.birthDate.getFullYear())); // ["2003-05-13T19:00:00.000Z", "1998-02-03T20:00:00.000Z"]
    console.log(this.childEndYear)
```

Comment: `"2003-05-13T19:00:00.000Z"` is a string ... `new Date("2003-05-13T19:00:00.000Z")` is a Date - hope that helps

Comment: You'd need to convert the date strings to date object. Then you can use appropriate methods such as `getFullYear`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just take a substring of the first 4 characters:

```js
var input = ["2003-05-13T19:00:00.000Z", "1998-02-03T20:00:00.000Z"]
for (var i=0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    year = input[i].substring(0, 4);
    console.log(input[i] + ", year: " + year)
}
```

But parsing to a date is also an option.  That would require that you know the format of the text dates.  But, since you already know that, you could just use a string operation.